# Approximating surface area with the multiple integral.

Tags: calculus

Hi I'm asking about how to rewrite the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} 1 \cdot \dfrac{\hat n}{| \hat n |} |\hat n|\Delta u \Delta v $ where $\hat n = r_{u}(u_{i}^{*},v_{j}^{*})\times r_{v}(u_{i}^{*},v_{j}^{*})$
as
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} 1 \cdot \dfrac{\hat n}{| \hat n |} |\hat n| du \Delta v $ where $\hat n = r_{u}(u_{i}^{*},v)\times r_{v}(u_{i}^{*},v)$. More concisely I'm trying to leave the cross product unevaluated... that is because of the paper at https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/multivariable/multivariable_15_Multiple_Integration.pdf:

[image: Reference. https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/multivariable/multivariable_15_Multiple_Integration.pdf]

Example 1) If the surface were $r(u,v) = \langle u, v, 1 \rangle$ then $\hat n = r_{u}(u_{i}^{*},v_{j}^{*})\times r_{v}(u_{i}^{*},v_{j}^{*}) = \langle 1, 0 , 0 \rangle \times \langle 0, 1 , 0 \rangle = \langle 0, 0 , 1 \rangle$ and that gives $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n}  1 \cdot \langle 0, 0 , 1 \rangle \Delta u \Delta v $ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} 0+0+1 du \Delta v$ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} ( u|_{\beta} - u|_{\alpha} ) \Delta v$.

Example 2) Suppose the surface had a normal vector $\hat n = \langle u_{i}^{*}, 0 , 0 \rangle \times \langle 0, v_{j}^{*} , 0 \rangle  = \langle 0, 0, u_{i}^{*}v_{j}^{*}\rangle$. I guess I can put $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n}  1 \cdot \langle u_{i}^{*}, 0 , 0 \rangle \times \langle 0, v_{j}^{*} , 0 \rangle \Delta u \Delta v $ as $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} 1 \cdot \langle u, 0 , 0 \rangle \times \langle 0, v_{j}^{*} , 0 \rangle  du \Delta v$ because it's also equal to $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} uv_{j}^{*} du \Delta v$ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{m} ( v_{j}^{*} u|_{\beta} - v_{j}^{*} u|_{\alpha} ) \Delta v$.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Does the step involving $r_{u}(u_{i}^{*},v)\times r_{v}(u_{i}^{*},v)$ really take place or do I have to simplify first by computing the cross product of $r_{u}(u_{i}^{*},v_{j}^{*})\times r_{v}(u_{i}^{*},v_{j}^{*})$?